# Apply normalize-space to all nodes

Tags: xml, xslt

I have an issue with this kind of XML tag

```
  <Foo>value
  </Foo>
```

After applying XSLT I got `"foo":"value\n      "`

So I used `normalize-space()` and it worked :

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="3.0"
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns:cbl="urn:chanel:names:specification:cbl:schema:xsd:CBLCore1.1.0"
  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions"
  exclude-result-prefixes="#all"
  expand-text="yes"
>
  <xsl:output method="text" encoding="UTF-8"/>

  <xsl:template match="//root">
    <xsl:variable name="xml">
      <map>
        <string key="foo">{normalize-space(Foo)}</string>
        <string key="bar">{normalize-space(Bar)}</string>
        <map key="moo">
          <map key="voo">
            <string key="startDate">{normalize-space(Moo/Voo/StartDate)}</string>
            <string key="endDate">{normalize-space(Moo/Voo/EndDate)}</string>
          </map>
        </map>
      </map>
    </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:value-of select="xml-to-json($xml)"/>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

But I don't want to set it for every element, How to apply it to **all** text node at once ?

I try also `normalize-space(xml-to-json($xml))` but it didn't work well it gives me `"foo":"value\n "`

Answer (score 0):

One way is to set up

```
<xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>

<xsl:template match="text()">
  <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space()"/>
</xsl:template>
```

then you use

```
<xsl:template match="/">
  <xsl:variable name="normalized-input">
   <xsl:apply-templates/>
  </xsl:variable>
  <xsl:value-of select="xml-to-json($normalized-input)"/>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Yes, this is a good case for a two-phase transformation. Depending on your operating environment, though, it might be better to write the two phases as separate stylesheets.